# How to write an HTML file that displays an HttpResponse object passed to it using Django

Tags: django-views, httpresponse, http-redirect

I am new to Django and HTML and I am trying to display a list of data derived from a form on the HttpResponseRedirect page. I have been reading Django APIs but I am still unsure of how to use HttpResponse() and HttpResponseRedirect().

As of now I understand that response = HttpResponse() makes an HttpResponse object of  and HttpResponseRedirect('results') redirects the browser to a new html template page. 
What I dont know is how to write results.html to display  on my browser.

I need help on how to write the HTML page.

I also need help on how to pass a list of data to that html page.

I would also be ok with displaying the list on the same html page the form is in instead of loading a new page.

Current code: 
    def contact(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
    form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    chosen = []
    if form.is_valid():
        strt = time.time()
        form = form.cleaned_data
        parameters = organize(form)
        print 'input organized'
        chosen, companies = multiple(parameters)
        end = time.time()
        pp.pprint(companies)
        print 'companies matching search filters: ' , len(companies)

        print 'total time: ' , str(end-strt)



    response = HttpResponse(chosen)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('results') # Redirect after POST
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is Django's [render_to_response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response) shortcut.  The first argument is an html template to use, and the second is a dictionary of values to pass to that template.

At the top of your views.py file, include:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
```

and modify your code to read:

```
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
    form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    chosen = []
    if form.is_valid():
        strt = time.time()
        form = form.cleaned_data
        parameters = organize(form)
        print 'input organized'
        chosen, companies = multiple(parameters)
        end = time.time()
        pp.pprint(companies)
        print 'companies matching search filters: ' , len(companies)
        print 'total time: ' , str(end-strt)
    return render_to_response('results.html', {'chosen':chosen,'companies':companies,'start':start,'end':end}) # Redirect after POST
```

Note that the second argument is a dictionary of values you'd like to pass to your template.  The way I've written it, you're passing 4 values (`chosen`, `companies`, `start`, `end`) but you can include as many as you'd like.

Then create a file named `results.html` in your Templates directory (which is specified in the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` variable in your `settings.py` file).  It could look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<h1>Results</h1>
<p>Chosen: {{chosen}}</p>
<p>Companies: {{companies}}</p>
<p>Start: {{start}}</p>
<p>End: {{end}}</p>
</body>
```

Django template syntax uses double curly braces `{{}}` to display variables passed to the template.

Note that this approach will not change the URL.  If you need to do this, try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463489/how-do-i-pass-template-context-information-when-using-httpresponseredirect-in-dj).