# Context with Render page in Django app

Tags: python, django

In my djangoApp , views.py I have :

```
status = True
context = {'status': status ,
           "form":ProfileForm()
          }
    return render(request, "sample/Newsample.html", context)
```

What if I want to use the context with redirect function? for example:

```
status = True
context = {'status': status ,
           "form":ProfileForm()
          }
    return redirect("sample/Newsample.html", context) - this does not work!!
```

How can I use context with redirect function?

Comment: What you want to do exactly ?

Comment: I have a variable in my template called status , which would display contents when status var is true. I want to pass this status var to Newsample.html through the redirect() func.

Comment: You're confusing redirect with render.  redirect sends you to a new url. Django will handle this url as it handles any other http request and create any context in the appropriate view.  You can pass a url, a url name, or a model(as long as it as get_absoluteurl() defined) to a redirect. docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

You wouldn't usually create a context object in a redirect view.  Well, if your view accepts a context variable (which would be less than orthodox), you could send one, but that would just be a bit necessary

Comment: DUPLICATE of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463489/how-do-i-pass-template-context-information-when-using-httpresponseredirect-in-dj and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624422/how-do-i-redirect-in-django-with-context

Comment: but if you wanted to you could also send them with some get variables

Comment: The behavior you're describing would probably be better served by a context processor than a redirect:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Comment: How to send it through get variables?

Answer (score 0):

**redirect** function doesn't any template as argument. It needs view name or url as the first argument.

Check this is required structure for **redirect**.

```
redirect(to[, permanent=False], *args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to send data with redirect, try this:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('some-view-name', status=True)
```

Comment: Tried this , sry it does not work this way , any other solution to this?

Comment: Can just paste the code, means what you have tried.

Comment: return redirect("sample/Newsample.html", status=True)

Comment: The first argument should be the view name, not the html file path. redirect(to[, permanent=False], *args, **kwargs)