# Django redirect from a view to another for further processing

Tags: django, redirect, parameter-passing

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
def AppAView(request)
     myData = Process(request)
     return myRedirect(url/to/AppBView, myData) # I want to pass myData to AppBView for 
                                                # further process

def AppBView(request)
     myData = Process(request)
     FurtherProcess(myData)
     return render(request, template[myData])
```

**AppAView** and **AppBView** potentially can be on different servers. What would be the best practice or at least a good/safe way of doing this in Django without explicitly passing myData as part of the url?

Thank you

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463489/how-do-i-pass-template-context-information-when-using-httpresponseredirect-in-dj (look at the second answer with more votes.. not the answer which is ticked off)

Comment: That answer uses HttpResponseRedirect(url) which redirects user to url, but I want to redirect the request to another server for further process.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably use [Sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) for that:

1. In AppAView, save `mydata` to request.session['mydata']
2. Redirect to AppBView
3. In AppBView check if request.session['mydata'] exists, if so further process it.

The challenging part would then be the cross-server session store and access. I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dustinfarris/6085132) which has a possible solution for a shared session store.